# Create data and controls dynamically in FormTemplate or NestedViewTemplate

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I am binding the RadGrid with the List of  QuestionManager Object as shown below:

```
public class QuestionManager
{
        public FormType FormType { get; set; }
        public Form Form { get; set; }
        public Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Question object further has a property of List.

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId{get;set;}
    public string QuestionNumber{get;set;}
    public List<Choice> ChoiceList{get;set;}
}
```

I am using a stored procedure that gets all the data and so no round trip is required.

The grid shows the FormType,FormName and Question # column.

When the edit button on each question is clicked,I need to populate all data and control available in List Object of the respective question.

To achieve this what should I use FormTemplate or NestedViewTemplate?

Is there a way where I can iterate the List in markup in a loop?

How should I get the List for each question?I dont want to hit the DB again as it will be expensive.

Is there any place in grid to store the List collection so that I need not have to hit the DB?

Answer (score 0):

I added the data rquired in DataKeyNames of MasterTableView of the RadGrid.
And in the ItemDataBound function,I m retrieving it.

```
<MasterTableView EnableViewState="true"  DataKeyNames="FormType.FormTypeCode,Form.FormId,Question.QuestionId,Question.ChoiceList">

string formTypeCode = radGrid.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["FormType.FormTypeCode"].ToString();
string formId = radGrid.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["Form.FormId"].ToString();
string questionId = radGrid.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["Question.QuestionId"].ToString();
Object objectChoiceList = radGrid.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["Question.ChoiceList"];

List<Choice> choiceList = null;

if (objectChoiceList != null)

choiceList = objectChoiceList as List<Choice>;

if (choiceList != null && choiceList.Count > 0)
{
//TODO:    
}
```